# What does lsof -ad3-999 -c rsync do?

Tags: process, lsof

I was trying to see the progress of a already running rsync and cp task and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/323782/850474) answer that allowed me to see what was currently happening

When i went to the `man` page for `lsof` and see that `-c` is what is used to select the process (`cp` in the example below) to look at and:

```
   -a       causes list selection options to be ANDed, as described above.

   -b       causes lsof to avoid kernel functions that might block - lstat(2), readlink(2), and stat(2).
```

But I don't really understand the combination with `3-999`

What does `lsof -ad3-999 -c cp` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-d3-999` just excludes the standard file descriptors (0,1,2) from the listing. The `-d` is used to specify a list or range of fds:

> ```
> -d s     specifies  a list of file descriptors (FDs) to exclude from or
>          include in the output listing.  The file descriptors are spec-
>          ified  in  the  comma-separated  set  s  -  e.g., ``cwd,1,3'',
>          ``^6,^2''.  (There should be no spaces in the set.)
>
>          The list is an exclusion list if all entries of the set  begin
>          with  `^'.   It  is  an inclusion list if no entry begins with
>          `^'.  Mixed lists are not permitted.
>
>          A file descriptor number range may be in the set  as  long  as
>          neither  member  is  empty,  both members are numbers, and the
>          ending member is larger than the starting one - e.g.,  ``0-7''
>          or  ``3-10''.   Ranges  may be specified for exclusion if they
>          have the  `^'  prefix  -  e.g.,  ``^0-7''  excludes  all  file
>          descriptors 0 through 7.
> ```

The guy who wrote that probably gave up on understanding why negated ranges do not work (just like me) and wrote it that way instead.